# How to calculate CI for percentage difference?

Tags: statistics

Suppose I have some paired data $(X,Y)$ and I wish to check if X is different to Y.

To do this I could simply use the paired t-test using the difference $(X_i - Y_i)$ for each $i$.

I can then use the paired t-test methodology this to form confidence intervals.

However what if I want to find the confidence intervals for the percentage difference, that is $\frac{X_i - Y_i}{X_i}$.

Can I just find the variance and mean of this percentage difference quantity and apply the t-test or is there another test I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer depends on how many pairs you have, and how far
the $X_i$ are from $0$, and how the $X_I$ and $Y_i$ are distributed.

Suppose there are $n$ pairs, then find all $n$ of the percentage
differences $R_i = (Y_i - X_i)/X_i$. The $R_i$ are unlikely to
be normal, but graph them to see if they are
'reasonably consistent' with normal (no far outliers, no
serious skewness). For moderate to large $n$ you should be
able to use a standard one-sample t confidence interval.

Note: I think you probably meant $(Y_i - X_i)/X_i,$ not
$(X_i - Y_i)/X_i,$ for percentage increase.

At first glance you might think this is an outrageous abuse of
a t procedure, but you might be surprised how much data are
already in terms of percentage increases, without the analyst
knowing that.

If data are too far from normal for a t interval, then you
might try a CI for the median or mean based on a nonparametric
procedure (Wilcoxon, bootstrap, etc.)
If the $X_i$ (denominator) can be negative or close to 0, then 
you need to re-think whether you really want to use percentage
increases as a measure.

For clarity, here is a quick demonstration (using R statistical software)  with $n = 50$ observations, for which the t interval works well. 
The x's are simulated as normal with mean 200 and SD 10, differences (y-x)'s
as normal with mean 5 and SD 0.5. The t confidence interval (shown
in the printout) for the *percentage* increases is $(2.41\%, 2.53\%).$ [Not shown: A straightforward
paired t test of y vs. x gives the CI $(4.896, 5.146)$ for the
mean difference. A Shapiro-Wilk test for normality fails to detect
that the data are other than normal; P-value 30%.]

```
 x = rnorm(50, 200, 10);  d = rnorm(50, 5, .5);  y = x + d
 r = (y - x)/x
 stripchart(r)  # omitted here, shows very mild right skewness
 t.test(r)
 ##   One Sample t-test  (data:  r) 
 ## t = 81.1063, df = 49, p-value < 2.2e-16
 ## alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0 
 ## 95 percent confidence interval:
 ## 0.02406902 0.02529204  # CI (2.41%, 2.53%) 

 round(r,3)  # print 'data' rounded to three places
 ## 0.022 0.026 0.027 0.028 0.025 0.025 0.025 0.023 0.024 0.025
 ## 0.023 0.027 0.026 0.021 0.025 0.027 0.026 0.026 0.022 0.025
 ## 0.030 0.026 0.027 0.022 0.026 0.023 0.022 0.028 0.021 0.028
 ## 0.021 0.023 0.028 0.026 0.026 0.026 0.022 0.026 0.025 0.023
 ## 0.023 0.024 0.026 0.023 0.023 0.023 0.024 0.024 0.027 0.025
 mean(r);  sd(r)
 ## 0.02468053    # sample mean of r
 ## 0.002151717   # sample SD
```

Comment: Thanks very much Bruce, very helpful.

Comment: @Mew: Good. Would be interested to know what works for your data. Maybe leave me a comment some day.

Comment: the percentage increase was normally distributed so I figure it is safe to use the standard T-test.  Good to know that this isn't a huge violation of statistics.